# During Installation, where do the Various File Types go on Vista

Tags: windows-vista, windows-xp, installation, program-files

Installing my software on Windows XP was always easy. Everything went in the "c:\Program Files\myprogram" directory. This included:

1. The executable program itself and any dlls.
2. Readme.txt and License.txt
3. The help files (.hlp or .chm or .pdf)
4. Program settings that are not in the registry (.ini files)
5. Sample data files for the program
6. Log files that the program produces

(Am I missing anything?)

But I understand that some of these should not go into the "Program Files" directory on Windows Vista. Which ones shouldn't and where should they go instead?

Also, should I change my XP install locations to match Vista?

---

Addenum: Some really good information was given in [an answer by François to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598196/rules-to-develop-a-delphi-windows-7-app/1598338#1598338) which pointed me to Marco Cantu's excellent post: [Non-Themed Windows Applications and Virtual Store](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/non_themed_virtual_storage.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant MSDN details for data placement:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762584(VS.85).aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You can keep most of the files in Program Files, you just need to move any files that need to be written to out of Program Files.

1. Program Files
2. Program Files
3. Program Files, or many all users
4. %APPDATA% for each user
5. Application Data folder for all users
6. Per user or all users temp folder