# Rules to Develop a Delphi Windows 7 App

Tags: delphi, windows-7, standards, rules

Where can I find the best set of rules to follow for developing a Delphi application for Windows 7?

Comment: What kind of rules are you looking for? Coding standards, UI guidelines, database access best practices?

Comment: Yes. Anything and everything specific to Windows 7 that may not (or may) have been applicable to XP or Vista. If it can differentiate what is new or different (e.g. file locations, or user authorization changes) that would be ideal. I am just basically unsure what I need to change or accommodate in my program as I attempt to go from XP development to Vista and Windows 7 development.

Comment: Some things have changes, but I think most stuff has really stayed the same. User data goes in \Users now, not in \Documents and Settings, but you should already be asking the OS for where special folders are. Set the glass settings as appropriate, of course. Make sure that your interface looks good in Segoe UI, and make sure the interface uses Tahoma in Windows XP and Segoe UI in Vista/7. Make sure you install as appropriate into Program Files or Program Files (x86). I can't think of too much else off the top of my head.

Comment: Anthony: Why not add that to your answer and delete the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can check out the [Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx)...

Mainly, the best thing to keep in mind is to follow the principle of least surprise. Make your app work the way your users expect your app to work. If it has pieces that look like Office, make them work like Office. If it has pieces that look like Explorer, make them work like Explorer.

Comment: Good comment. But even Office's interface has changed, and radically at that with the introduction of the Ribbon.

Answer (score 2):

2 recent posts by Marco on this subject:
[Old Delphi Applications More Compatible with Windows 7](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/old_delphi_compatibility_windows7.html)
[Non Themed Windows Applications and Virtual Store](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/non_themed_virtual_storage.html)

Comment: That 2nd link would have been a great answer to my question: "During Installation, where do the Various File Types go on Vista". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427164/during-installation-where-do-the-various-file-types-go-on-vista  Thanks for that.